# How to set the time zone in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, timezone, timezone-offset

How do I set the runtime time zone in Google Cloud Functions in JavaScript? I mean not in a specific Date object, but globally.

By default, calling `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` returns `UTC` and calling `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns `0`.

How do I configure GCF or how do I update the runtime environment so that `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` returns `Europe/Berlin` and calling `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns `-120`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure the timezone on a Cloud Functions server instance.